# How to query and list different items from one row Psql

Tags: postgresql

So I have a single row in a table with about 3000 different items ranging from wood nails glue and finish.

Id like to make a query where I can see how many of each I have.

any help would be great

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is

```
SELECT item_type, COUNT(item_id)
FROM different_items
GROUP BY item_type
```

Adjust it to your particular database.